# How to do AutoLayout programmatically with Horizontal scrolling?

Tags: ios, autolayout, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to do Horizontal scrolling on iOS using AutoLayout programmatically. Here's the link to my [github](https://github.com/noppanit/UIScrollViewAutoLayout) I'm trying to add another `NewsSection` to the next page but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's the code I'm working on.

```
- (void) setupNewsView
{
    UIView *newsView = [[NewsSection alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    newsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView *anotherNewsView = [[NewsSection alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    anotherNewsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    newsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    anotherNewsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:newsView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:anotherNewsView];

    NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{ @"newsView": newsView, @"anotherNewsView": anotherNewsView };

    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[newsView]|"
                                                                            options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:viewsDict]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[newsView]|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:viewsDict]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               multiplier:1.0f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               multiplier:1.0f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];


    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[anotherNewsView(200)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[anotherNewsView(100)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];


    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Right now the app looks like this. What I want is user should be able to scroll to the right and see the blue screen. What constraint do I need to add?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints you have set the blue view to fill the scroll view AND to be of a fixed width, which causes a conflict. The |s at either end of the constraint string make anotherNewsView hug the bounds of its superview (scrollView).

Try dropping the final |s from your constraints. Also position anotherNewsView to be left-aligned with newsView rather than scrollView.

These constraints should do the trick:

```
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[newsView(500)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[newsView(500)][anotherNewsView(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
[self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[anotherNewsView(200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the constraints. They work but I can't still scroll to the left. When I scroll to the left I see the blue rectangle stick to the end of the red rectangle but I can't scroll to the second page.

Comment: Also it looks like you specify the width of newsView to 500. However, I was hoping that the first page would fill up the whole screen and the next page (red background) would fill up for another page. I will have more pages going forward.